# Change format of Array string

Tags: arrays, vb.net, date

I currently run an array which reads 6 or so lines from a text file. Below is an example of how i'm extracting the required information from the lines in the text file

```
line = allLines.Where(Function(x) (x.StartsWith("plandate="))).SingleOrDefault()
            If line IsNot Nothing Then
                AllDetails(numfiles).pDate = line.Split("="c)(1)
            End If
```

In this instance I'm extracting the planned date in the format `dd/MM/yy`

For part of a sub I need to change the reference of the format from `dd/MM/yy` to `dd MMMM yy`.

I've tried the following

`Dim uPland As String = AllDetails(n).pDate.ToString("dd MMMM yy")`

however i get the following error message

`Unable to cast object of type 'System.String' to type 'System.IFormatProvider'.`

The format needs to be changed as I folders which are created with dates as a title using the `dd MMMM yy` format.

If anymore code is needed to be posted then please let me know

Any guidance please

Comment: What datatype is `pDate`?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI I've managed to sort the issue using the following

```
Dim uPland As String = Date.Parse(AllDetails(n).pDate).ToString("dd MMMM yy")
```

Answer (score 2):

Currently you're never parsing the values as `DateTime` values - which means you can't *format* them as `DateTime` either. The only single-parameter `ToString` method on `String` is the one with `IFormatProvider` as the parameter type, which is why you're getting the error you are.

I suggest you change the type of `pDate` from `String` to `DateTime`, parse (e.g. using `DateTime.ParseExact`) when you read the file, and then convert back to text in whatever format you're interested in *only* when you really need to do so.